# vue js firebase изменить значение в бд

Tags: vue.js, firebase

Помогите разобраться...
Разрабатываю приложение на vue js + firebasе ...
В одном из компонентов  я из бд вытягиваю таблицу с orders, пропускаю ее через  v-for  и вывожу на страницу ...
там есть   input  типа checkbox   при клике на который должно изменится значение в бд  in_work  с false  на true

Структура Бд в Firebase.....

```
ORDERS:
   -LEs1FCRFIqvpDnqTxIF
      - 0
            adress: ""
           comment: ""
             email: "*****@yandex.ru"
         firstname: "gary"
           in_work: false
```

......

```
  <p>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="order['.value'][0]['in_work']"  v-on:click="checkbox_value(order['.key'])">
        <label for="checkbox">IN WORK</label>
    </p>
```

....
если делаю этим методом ...

```
  methods:{
      checkbox_value(key){
          OrdersRef.child(key)[0].update({in_work : true});
                         }
```

--выдает ошибку ...Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

Вопрос:
не могу разобраться как это сделать